# How to order a model by id in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using heroku to run a quiz app.

```
class Question
  belongs_to :quiz
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
end
```

So I generate the quiz using something like this:

```
<%  @questions.each do |question| %>

 // put questions here

  <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>

   // put answers here.

  <% end #answer.each do %>   

<% end #questions.each do %>
```

It's easy enough to order @questions. In my controller I have:

```
@quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
@questions = @quiz.questions.order(:id)
```

so just using `order(:id)` I can ensure the questions are displaying in order of their id. I can't figure out a way to order answers the same way.

`@answers = @questions.answers.order(:id)` doesn't work because I assume ruby doesn't know which question I'm using. I can't just use `has_many :answers, through: :questions` in my `Quiz` model because then for every question, all the answers will be displayed. I want to somehow sort the answers in my view by id, something like

`question.answers.order(:id).each` but when I do this nothing happens (because maybe Array doesn't have the order method?) What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how answers should actually be sorted. Could you give more details (perhaps even sharing some potential values and expected output?).

Comment: You can add default scopes to your models to order by the ID and rails should add it to all queries for you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for what you want?

```
    @questions.each do |question|  
      @answers = question.answers.order(:id)
    end
```

Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

So, the way you have your relationship set up, each question has a method answers that returns the list of all the answers associated with the question.

So, when you loop through each question, you can get that list of answers and then sort that.

```
<%  @questions.each do |question| %>

// put questions here

  <% question.answers.order(:id).each do |answer| %>

   // put answers here.

  <% end #answer.each do %>  

<% end #questions.each do %>
```